# Why isn't carbon-14 included in CIAAW list of isotopic abundances?

Tags: isotope, carbon-family

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_atomic_weight), standard atomic weight is based on the published isotopic abundances of [CIAAW](https://www.ciaaw.org/):

> The standard atomic weight $(A_\mathrm{r},$ standard) of a [chemical element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_element) is the [weighted arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean) of the relative atomic masses $(A_\mathrm{r})$ of all [isotopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotope) of that element [weighted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean) by each isotope's abundance on Earth. The standard atomic weight of each chemical element is determined and published by the [Commission on Isotopic Abundances and Atomic Weights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commission_on_Isotopic_Abundances_and_Atomic_Weights) (CIAAW) of the [International Union of Pure and Applied Chemistry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Union_of_Pure_and_Applied_Chemistry) (IUPAC) based on natural, stable, [terrestrial](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/terrestrial) sources of the element.

However, [this table of isotopic abundances](https://www.ciaaw.org/isotopic-abundances.htm) appears to be incomplete — for example, it's missing carbon-14.

Are they only listing primordial isotopes, or maybe those above some threshold of abundance? Is there some other criteria?

Why is carbon-14 not listed?

Comment: I guess this is because we have very few of it.

Comment: According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon), the abundance is about a part per trillion, so the imprecision in the abundances of the two main isotopes dwarfs that.

Comment: Maybe C-14 isn't that abundant.

Comment: Also, what was quoted also says **stable** ...

Comment: The CIAAW source specifically says under carbon: "Yet, this isotope never occurs in normal carbon sources in concentrations high enough to affect significantly the Ar(C) value."

Comment: @JonCuster Thanks! I hadn't seen that, but searching for your text I find it on https://ciaaw.org/carbon.htm

Comment: Also, 14C abundance varies with location: almost none in geological sources, highest in green, growing plants or other carbon sinks.

Comment: It's what Ed says: C-14 is not stable.

Comment: @BuckThorn I'm confused by that statement. The table includes three isotopes of uranium, all of which are radioactive. Is there some other meaning for "stable" besides "not radioactive"? And if not, and only stable isotopes factor into the standard atomic weight, how can we even have a standard atomic weight for elements like uranium which have no stable isotopes?

Comment: No, I was thinking specifically radioactive. I suppose with uranium one doesn't really have a choice since all isotopes are radioactive, but they are always found together in the same proportions? But I retract my previous comment, since you are right. The alternative explanations (extremely low and variable natural abundance) must account for the absence of the isotope in the table. Actually, the comments in the table explain that natural sources of U can show variability outside of the tabulated limits.

Comment: As per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/rhenium), Re, In and Te only have minority abundance stable isotopes, so *stable* has to yield to pragmatic reality: theory guides, experiment decides, as they say. For uranium, all the isotopes are radioactive, so *stable* is not applicable. For carbon, the relative abundances make it a moot point.

Comment: From the wikipedia articles on [Carbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon) and [Isotopes of carbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_carbon), the atomic weight of carbon, in Daltons, is just the weighted average. Thus, AW = (0.9893 x 12) + (0.0107 x 13.00335483521) + (1 ppt x 14.003241988) = 11.872 + 0.139 + 10 ppt = 12.011, as in the periodic table.

Comment: On a final note, the OP’s linked table of isotopic abundances shows that no listed isotope has an abundance given to more than 6 decimal places, except for La and Ta, which both have 7 decimal place listed abundances. So carbon 14’s abundance is in the 12-th decimal place and it is entirely negligible.